# Can't find nmap executable in Metasploit

Tags: arch-linux, metasploit

I'm running Metasploit in archlinux and when I execute

```
msf> db_nmap -h
```

It'll return an error:

```
The nmap executable could not be found
```

Now, I know I am probably missing a binary or something, but how did I end up missing it? I installed `ruby1.9` and `metasploit-git` from the AUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `nmap` is a package and I simply had to install it.

```
pacman -S nmap
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure metasploit was installed in a location that's on your `$PATH`? You likely installed it to `/usr/local` or some such directory which isn't on your system or user's default `$PATH`.

If the executables were installed on your system and a day or so has gone by your system's filesystem indexing task may have picked it up. This would be one way to locate it using the `locate` command.

```
$ locate <metasploit executable>
```

If you've just only recently installed it then look at the installation notes and/or script that was used to do the install and see where it was installed. You can also do a full system search using `find`.

```
$ find /usr -iname "<metasploit executable>"
```

But this command will take some time to walk your entire `/usr` sub-directory.